# Django manage.py runserver command requested resource was not found on this server error

Tags: python, django

I have just today started working with django.

I tried executing the run server command but I keep encountering the `Page not found error`.

I have been trying to debug the problem for almost an hour now.

Project rms > myrms (app)

## Edit:

I have initally doubly defined url patterns statement which was pointed out by meshy. I corrected that error but still the code is not working. Help.

### myrms/view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello,World. You're at the polls index.")
```

### myrms/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name = 'index'),
    path('myrms/', include('myrms.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

It's expected to show the hello world statement but keeps on turning up `Page not found error`
on running manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 18, 2019 - 18:41:24
Django version 2.1.7, using settings 'RMS.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[18/Feb/2019 18:41:36] "GET /myrms/ HTTP/1.1" 404 77
```

I am trying to open. url"http://localhost:8000/myrms/" or "http://127.0.0.1:8000/myrms/" both are showing error

Comment: to serve index change url pattern `''` to `'^$'`

Comment: Hi. Can you please elaborate how that helps>

Comment: Please add some information: a) what do you get after `python manage.py runserver`, b) which url you are trying to open, c) stack trace of error - copy-paste text from "Page not found error", d) look at your command line - what `manage.py runserver` printing?

Comment: You've modified your question, and my answer is now obsolete.

Comment: @meshy you helped to remove another error. It must be of help for OP in any case

Comment: @meshy I have removed the edit suggested by yugandhar chaudhari and made it specific to the answer you gave me.

Comment: Can you show content off `myrms.urls`?

Comment: @pbacterio its already there in the question

Comment: @user11079079 so are you making a recursive include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including this file, *from* this file recursively.

Remove this line, it's redundant because you're writing it from within `myrms/urls.py`:

```
path('myrms/', include('myrms.urls')),
```

Change the URL of your view to match the URL you're accessing:

```
path('myrms/', views.index,name = 'index'),
```

Alternatively, access a different URL: http://localhost:8000/

Ensure that `ROOT_URLCONF` is set to `myrms.urls`.

**Another old answer**

You are using `'^$'`, but that is for `re_path()`, not `path()`.

```
path('', views.index,name = 'index'),
```

**Original answer, before question changed**

You've defined `urlpatterns` twice. The second time you define it, you override the first.

To correct this, combine the two lists:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name = 'index'),
    path('myrms/', include('myrms.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: I corrected the url file and I also used that '' to '^$' change still it shows page not found error

Comment: Please tell me a suitable tutorial available online that can help me learn django